# OracleSolaris 11.2 - locate capability of PCI device

Tags: solaris, device-driver, pci, pci-e, opensolaris

I need solaris analogue to linux's `pci_find_capability` kernel function. I grepped through `/usr/src/` for some similarities, but didn't find anything close to it. What do pci/pcie drivers normally use to find capabilities supported by devices? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`<sys/sunddi.h>` has `pcie_get_cap()`, but apart from that the drivers I'm aware of just go and read the pci/pcie device config space directly looking for the info that they're after.

What problem are you trying to solve here?